# .env not setting variables

Tags: dotenv

I am following this course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ and so far so good, but when I try to set up variables in my .env file it simply doesn't work. It's like I am writing in a blank notepad. Maybe I don't have

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It usually does look like that and here's an example below. There might be an extension in VS Code that will make it look nicer. Does that answer your question?

```
API_URL="api_url_here"
PUBLIC_KEY="public_key_here"
PRIVATE_KEY="private_key_here"
```